# Uncountable Pre-Image

Tags: real-analysis

I've been reading about space filling curves, and been asking myself this question.

If $f: \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous open map, is it true that $\forall x \in$ range$(f)$ , $f^{-1}(x)$ is always uncountable?

Comment: No, some points may have countable, finite, even unique inverse images.

Comment: Is there a relatively trivial example? I cannot seem to think of one...

Comment: Incidentally, there are continuous surjections $f: S^1\to S^2$ so that every preimage contains at most 3 points. (Actually, with countably many exceptions, preimage contains at most 2 points.) 

Comment: You are right.  I was thinking of a space-filling curve, which this is not.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think so, yes. Let $x$ be in the range of $f$ and define $U = f^{-1}((-\infty, x))$, $V = f^{-1}((x,\infty))$. Since $f$ is open, $U$ and $V$ are both nonempty. So they are disjoint nonempty open sets, which means that the complement of $f^{-1}(x)$ is disconnected. But the complement of any countable subset of ${\bf R}^2$ is connected. (Even path connected, by a simple cardinality argument: for any distinct $p$ and $q$ one can find uncountably many paths from $p$ to $q$, any two of which are disjoint except for the points $p$ and $q$. So a countable set can obstruct only countably many of them.)

Comment: Actually, I only used the fact that the range of $f$ is open, not that $f$ is an open map.

Comment: Also, my argument actually shows that $f^{-1}(x)$ has cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$, for those who care about such niceties.

Comment: Many thanks! One follow up question: How does your definition of U and V imply that the complement of $f^{-1}(x)$ is disconnected?

Comment: @John: The complement of $f^{-1}(x)$ is disconnected because it is the disjoint union of two nonempty open sets, $U$ and $V$.

Comment: Oh, one more comment. I wish I'd thought of saying this earlier. The proof that the complement of any countable subset of ${\bf R}^2$ is connected *goes back to Cantor*. I remember reading it in Dauben's biography.